# Как подключить JS-плагин в SonataAdminBundle в Symfony4?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, sonata

Нужно поставить маску на ввод номера телефона в SonataAdminBundle, то есть, чтобы пользователю она помогала вводить нужный номер телефона. Для этого нужно подключить какой-то плагин, например, jQuery-mask-plugin. Куда его подключать? Я пробовал положить его в node_modules, но мне это ничего не дало. Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда его вставить, чтобы он заработал в админской JS.

Прилагаю код из jquery.js, полученный с помощью console.trace();:

1)

```
ret = ( (jQuery.event.special[ handleObj.origType ] || {}).handle || handleObj.handler )
                            .apply( matched.elem, args );
```

2)

```
jQuery.event.dispatch.apply( elem, arguments ) : undefined;
```

Если я добавляю плагин, то ошибка проявляется по-другому. Подскажите, пожалуйста, нормальный плагин для маски телефона +7 ### ###-##-##.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы решить проблему, нужно использовать плагин maskedinput.js и в основном *.js файле записать следующий код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('.mask_js')){
    $('.mask_js').each(function() {
        $(this).mask('+7 *** ***-**-**');
    });
    }
});
```